# cannot join to master node using kubeadm join

Tags: centos, kubernetes

I am trying to set up a kubernetes cluster and running this command on my worker node
`kubeadm join server:port --token xxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx`
and the error i have is

```
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

I am not sure which container runtime to use here, so i modified the command as
`kubeadm join server:port --token xxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx --cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock`
but the error is

```
[ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: I0617 21:55:27.908044 1877581 util_unix.go:103] "Using this endpoint is deprecated, please consider using full URL format" endpoint="/var/run/crio/crio.sock" URL="unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock"
E0617 21:55:27.908867 1877581 remote_runtime.go:616] "Status from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/crio/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
time="2023-06-17T21:55:27+05:30" level=fatal msg="getting status of runtime: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/crio/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
, error: exit status 1
```

Can someone suggest the correct approach here

Comment: You’re not wrong to post this on ServerFault but I’ll tell you from experience it’s not super likely you’ll get responses here. You would probably be better off on stackoverflow or the Unix stack exchange.

Comment: As far as your question, podman is the preferred runtime for K8s. Docker w/K8s frequently breaks because Docker makes no effort to stay CRIO compliant (at least that has been my experience)